# How to Clear All Cache in Play Framework 2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

So I'm using Play's built in cache API as seen here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaCache

In my code I've already set the cache to expire every 10 minutes. I am also using the session cache style.

So my main question is, since it's gonna be really hard to keep track of all cache, how do I clear all of the cache? I know that using Play's default cache is minimal but it's working perfectly for me at this point. I just want the ability to clear the cache once in awhile just in case too many sessions are made and somewhere in my code it's piling up the caches.

Comment: how did you clear cache ?

Answer (score 4):

The [Play Java API](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/java/play/cache/Cache.java) does not provide a way to clear the whole cache.

You'll have to use your own cache plugin, or extends [the existing one](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cache.scala) to provide this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Well I know one way of clearing the cache is recompile the code.

Answer (score 3):

here's an example if your using default EhCachePlugin

```
import play.api.Play.current

...

for(p <- current.plugin[EhCachePlugin]){
  p.manager.clearAll
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @alessandro.negrin for pointing how to access EhCachePlugin.

Here are some further details in that direction. Tested using Play 2.2.1 default EhCachePlugin:

```
  import play.api.cache.Cache
  import play.api.Play
  import play.api.Play.current
  import play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin

  // EhCache is a Java library returning i.e. java.util.List
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

  // Default Play (2.2.x) cache name 
  val CACHE_NAME = "play"

  // Get a reference to the EhCachePlugin manager
  val cacheManager = Play.application.plugin[EhCachePlugin]
    .getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("EhCachePlugin not loaded")).manager

  // Get a reference to the Cache implementation (here for play)
  val ehCache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME)
```

Then you have access to Cache instance methods such as **[ehCache.removeAll()](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#removeAll%28%29)**:

```
  // Removes all cached items.
  ehCache.removeAll()
```

*Please note this is different than [cacheManager.clearAll()](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/management/CacheManager.html#clearAll%28%29) described by @alessandro.negrin 
which according to the doc: "Clears the contents of all caches in the CacheManager,(...)", 
potentially other ehCache than "play" cache.*

In addition you have access to Cache methods such as `getKeys` that might allow you to 
select a subset of keys containing a `matchString`, for instance to perform remove operations to:

```
  val matchString = "A STRING"

  val ehCacheKeys = ehCache.getKeys() 

  for (key <- ehCacheKeys) {
    key match {
      case stringKey: String => 
        if (stringKey.contains(matchString)) { ehCache.remove(stringKey) }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Play 2.5.x one can access `EhCache` directly injecting `CacheManagerProvider` and use the full `EhCache` API:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import net.sf.ehcache.{Cache, Element}
import play.api.cache.CacheManagerProvider
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class MyController @Inject()(cacheProvider: CacheManagerProvider) extends Controller {
    def testCache() = Action{
        val cache: Cache = cacheProvider.get.getCache("play")
        cache.put(new Element("key1", "val1"))
        cache.put(new Element("key2", "val3"))
        cache.put(new Element("key3", "val3"))
        cache.removeAll()
        Ok
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an Akka system scheduler and Actor to clear your caches at given intervals then set it to run in your Global file. The [Play Cache api](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/cache/Cache.java) doesn't have a method to list all of your keys, but I use scheduler jobs to manage clearing the cache by using Cache.remove manually on my list of cache keys. If you're using [Play 2.2](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/java/play/cache) the Cache module moved. Some caching modules have an api to clear the entire cache.

Answer (score 0):

Store all keys that you use for caching in a Set e.g. HashSet and when you want to delete the entire cache just iterate over the set and call

```
Iterator iter = cacheSet.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   Cache.remove(iter.next());
}
```