# CSS not changing while using Play Framework

Tags: java, html, css, playframework

I am trying to make changes to my CSS while editing my web app. Any changes I make to the file are not reflected once I reload the page. I know it is linked to the correct CSS sheet as if I remove it from the directory the page loads plain HTML. Is there a way to make changes to the CSS and have them reflected straight away in the application? The CSS I have already written displays fine, it just does not change "live".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")'>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache in your browser?  I believe the framework only recognizes updates to files that have to be compiled, which the CSS files aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely seems like a cache issue. CSS changes will change live when there is no cache system. Try doing a force reload of the page (ctrl+F5 win, Apple + R mac, F5 linux). You may also need to clear the playframework cache (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682536/how-to-clear-all-cache-in-play-framework-2-1) for info on how to do that).